# Create a polygon shapefile using point as boundary

Tags: qgis, python

Following have two problems:

1. I am now have 4 point in a shapefile and I want to set the point's coordinate for boundary of a polygon

   The points are xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax that can just be a rectangular polygon.
2. I want to make it to create a shapefile to make difference with another polygon shapefile

above problems i want to do it with python script

any ideas?

I use QGIS 1.8.0 and python 2.7.3

Comment: Try the following: 1. use convex hull on the points --> should give you the polygon, 2. use difference. Is that the result you are looking for? Do you need a python script or would a Sextante geoprocessing model help too?

Comment: In fact, I need python method to do this two, i can do it with plugin qgis provide,but I want to do it with python

Comment: Check this [post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49741/python-ogr-convert-a-point-geometry-into-polygon)